# PowerShell on Windows: Start-Process fails if output redirection arguments are used

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, process, redirection

Why does `Start-Process` fail to find the executable (not in the path) if `-RedirectStandardOutput` or `-RedirectStandardError` are specified?

I.e.

```
[X:\] Start-Process -FilePath "prog.exe" -WorkingDirectory (Get-Location).Path
```

The program starts & executes as it should. But when I add output redirection, everything falls apart:

```
[X:\] Start-Process -FilePath "prog.exe" -WorkingDirectory (Get-Location).Path -RedirectStandardOutput stdout.txt
Start-Process: This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Redirecting with the `1>stdout.txt` operator works as expected.

This seems not to affect programs that reside in directories listed in `PATH`. I cannot really figure out what's the logic here. Redirections should have nothing to do with resolving the binary path in the first place.

Running on Windows 10 Professional.

**Update**: Full trace & simple reproducer

```
PS> cat .\hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        printf("Meh\n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
}

PS> cl hello.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30138 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30138.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello.exe
hello.obj

PS> Start-Process -FilePath hello.exe -WorkingDirectory (Get-Location).Path

PS> Start-Process -FilePath hello.exe -WorkingDirectory (Get-Location).Path -RedirectStandardOutput stdout.txt
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process -FilePath hello.exe -WorkingDirectory (Get-Location).Pa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

**Update 2**:

Seems that using absolute path for the executable is a workaround for the issue. (Although it doesn't explain why output direction breaks the executable name/path resolution in the first place)

Comment: Weird… What's output from `where.exe "prog.exe"`? Before and after the _running_  example (i.e. without any `-RedirectStandard` parameter)? Maybe `prog.exe` changes `$env:PATH` or a drive mapping?

Comment: The output of the program doesn't really matter/have any effect, as the breakage happens in PowerShell, before the program is even executed. The programs I'm trying to execute using this scheme are all Windows console apps without GUI.

Updated the question with a minimal reproducer.

Comment: Forgot to add that the program to be run is our internal application, so I know it is not tinkering with `PATH` -- unless the MSVC CRT implementation does something fishy when output is piped :)

Comment: Process Monitor will show you the file path where it is attempting to save/redirect the output when only the file name is specified.

Comment: I did check with Process Monitor and there was no errors wrt. output file access. Also took a quick peek at the PowerShell source code as well, and seems like the output direction triggers code path that basically requires the executable to be found from the `PATH` when the path to executable is relative.

Comment: What if you change the testing scenario? Run `Start-Process -FilePath hello.exe -WorkingDirectory (Get-Location).Path -RedirectStandardOutput stdout.txt` (**with** the `-RedirectStandardOutput`) **at first**, and then _without_ the `-RedirectStandardOutput` parameter…

Comment: @JosefZ Ordering of the parameters doesn't seem to have any effect (and they shouldn't, since all of them are keyword arguments. And as I mentioned above, the presence of `-RedirectStandardOutput` triggers code path that seems to have stricter prerequisites than the path w/o redirection).

Comment: @huoneusto I don't mean order of the _parameters_. I mean **order of the commands**. Run **command** with the `-RedirectStandardOutput` _before_ the one _without_ it…

Comment: @JosefZ Sorry, I misread your comment first; Execution order doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Take the full path for the executable.

[See my screenhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHvnd.png)

I don't have a full explanation... but i can remember it has something to do with ShellExecute and CreateProcess in c++

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew

My best guess would be that shellexecute is the problem.
In the docs you can find.

```
ShellExecute(handle, NULL, <fully_qualified_path_to_folder>, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

The Redirect parameter may change the underlying calls.
See .NET equivalent.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-6.0

Comment: It's the PowerShell implementation of `Start-Process` -- Enabling output redirection introduces additional constraint to the executable location (has to be in `PATH`). 

I assume this is a bug/unintentional feature as those two - output direction & executable location - don't seem connected at all (not to me, at least).